# How to multiply the column dynamically based on the condition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my Query which is dynamic

```
DECLARE @companyids nvarchar(1024) = '77',
@fromYear Int = 2015,
@toYear Int = 2023,
@fiscalPeriodType Int = 3,
@lang smallint = 1,
@frIds nvarchar(1024) = '109,4'



Declare @sql As nvarchar(max), @periods nvarchar(max), @financialRatioTable nvarchar(max), @financialRatioNames nvarchar(max) , @Id  nvarchar(max) , @Multiplier bit
    Select @sql = N'', @periods = N'', @financialRatioTable = N'', @financialRatioNames = N'' , @Id = N'' , @Multiplier = 0

Select @financialRatioNames = STRING_AGG(ColumnName, ',') FROM FinancialRatioConfigs WHERE FinancialRatioID IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@frIds, ','))


SELECT  @Id =  (SELECT CAST(LEFT(@frIds, CHARINDEX(',', @frIds + ',') - 1) AS INT)) 

Select @Multiplier =  ShowPercentage FROM FinancialRatioConfigs WHERE FinancialRatioID = @Id

Select distinct @financialRatioTable = F.AssociatedFRTable
From CompanyArgaamSectors CAS
Inner Join ArgaamSectorFSTemplates AFS On AFS.ArgaamSectorID = CAS.ArgaamSectorID
Inner Join FSTemplates F On AFS.FSTemplateID = F.FSTemplateID
Where CAS.CompanyID in (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@companyids, ','))
and AFS.IsActive = 1
and CAS.IsDefault = 1

Select @sql = N'
Select * from (
            Select CompanyID, CompanyNameAr, CompanyNameEn, FinancialYear, FiscalPeriodID, FiscalPeriodTypeID, FiscalPeriodValue, ForDate,
            '+@financialRatioNames+'
            From '+@financialRatioTable+'
            Where CompanyID In('+@companyids +') And FiscalPeriodTypeID = '+Cast(@fiscalPeriodType as nvarchar) +' And IsPublish = 1
            AND FinancialYear >= '+CAST(@fromYear AS nvarchar(10))+' AND FinancialYear <= '+CAST(@toYear AS nvarchar(10)) +'
            )V
            Order By ForDate Asc'

  Select * from (
                Select CompanyID, CompanyNameAr, CompanyNameEn, FinancialYear, FiscalPeriodID, FiscalPeriodTypeID, FiscalPeriodValue, ForDate,
                BookValue,TotalShareholdersEquity
                From FROthers
                Where CompanyID In(77) And FiscalPeriodTypeID = 3 And IsPublish = 1
                AND FinancialYear >= 2015 AND FinancialYear <= 2023
                )V
                Order By ForDate Asc
```

I want to add condition that if the @multiplier is 1 than i want to multiply the columns with 100 like this

```
Select * from (
            Select CompanyID, CompanyNameAr, CompanyNameEn, FinancialYear, FiscalPeriodID, FiscalPeriodTypeID, FiscalPeriodValue, ForDate,
            BookValue * 100 AS BookValue,TotalShareholdersEquity * 100 AS TotalShareholdersEquity
            From FROthers
            Where CompanyID In(77) And FiscalPeriodTypeID = 3 And IsPublish = 1
            AND FinancialYear >= 2015 AND FinancialYear <= 2023
            )V
            Order By ForDate Asc
```

Keep in mind that I also want alias same as column name after multiplying the column with 100

Comment: FYI, when building dynamic SQL you should *always* use `QUOTENAME` to delimit identify your dynamic object names,. Also don't *inject* your parameters (for example `'...'+CAST(@fromYear AS nvarchar(10))+'...'`), *parametrise* them. There should no no injection in your `WHERE` clause in the code you've given us.

Answer (score 0):

This is *impossible* for me to test as there is no sample data, nor expected results. if this doesn't work you'll need to use "your best friend" to help you here.

I've added a `CASE` expression to the assignment of the value of `@@FinancialRatioNames`and moved it's position so that `@Multiplier` is defined.

I've also fixed other problems, such as the wealth of injection you had, lack of delimit identification, data types, unused variables, and missing schemas. There are other comments in there though that need addressing though that I can't consider.

```sql
DECLARE @Companyids nvarchar(1024) = N'77',
        @FromYear int = 2015,
        @ToYear int = 2023,
        @FiscalPeriodType int = 3,
        @Lang smallint = 1,
        @frIds nvarchar(1024) = N'109,4';



DECLARE @SQL AS nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10),
        --@periods nvarchar(max), --This is never used, what is it for?
        @FinancialRatioTable sysname, --Correct data type
        @FinancialRatioNames nvarchar(MAX),
        @Id nvarchar(MAX), --Will your ID really be over 4,000 characters in length? It's a poor choice for an ID if so.
        @Multiplier bit;
/*
SELECT @SQL = N'',
       --@periods = N'', 
       @financialRatioTable = N'',
       @financialRatioNames = N'' ,
       @Id = N'' ,
       @Multiplier = 0
*/


SELECT @Id = (SELECT CAST(LEFT(@frIds, CHARINDEX(',', @frIds + ',') - 1) AS int));

SELECT @Multiplier = ShowPercentage
FROM dbo.FinancialRatioConfigs
WHERE FinancialRatioID = @Id;

SELECT @FinancialRatioNames = STRING_AGG(CONCAT(QUOTENAME(ColumnName),CASE @Multiplier WHEN 1 THEN ' * 100' END, ' AS ', QUOTENAME(ColumnName)), ',')
FROM dbo.FinancialRatioConfigs
WHERE FinancialRatioID IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@frIds, ','));

--This statement makes no sense; it'll assign an arbitrary value to @FinancialRatioTable
SELECT --DISTINCT --This makes no sense, the value is already arbitrary, adding a DISINCT changes nothing.
       @FinancialRatioTable = F.AssociatedFRTable 
FROM dbo.CompanyArgaamSectors CAS
     INNER JOIN dbo.ArgaamSectorFSTemplates AFS ON AFS.ArgaamSectorID = CAS.ArgaamSectorID
     INNER JOIN dbo.FSTemplates F ON AFS.FSTemplateID = F.FSTemplateID
WHERE CAS.CompanyID IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Companyids, ','))
  AND AFS.IsActive = 1
  AND CAS.IsDefault = 1;

Select @SQL = N'SELECT CompanyID,' + @CRLF +
              N'       CompanyNameAr,' + @CRLF +
              N'       CompanyNameEn,' + @CRLF +
              N'       FinancialYear,' + @CRLF +
              N'       FiscalPeriodID,' + @CRLF +
              N'       FiscalPeriodTypeID,' + @CRLF +
              N'       FiscalPeriodValue,' + @CRLF +
              N'       ForDate,' + @CRLF +
              N'       ' + @FinancialRatioNames + @CRLF +
              N'FROM dbo.'+QUOTENAME(@financialRatioTable) + @CRLF  + --Guess Schema name
              N'WHERE CompanyID IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@CompanyIds,'','')' + @CRLF +
              N'  AND FiscalPeriodTypeID = @fiscalPeriodType' + @CRLF +
              N'  AND IsPublish = 1' + @CRLF +
              N'  AND FinancialYear >= @FromYear' + @CRLF +
              N'  AND FinancialYear <= @ToYear' + @CRLF +
              N'ORDER BY ForDate Asc;';

--PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Companyids nvarchar(1024), @FiscalPeriodType int, @FromYear int, @ToYear int', @Companyids, @FiscalPeriodType, @FromYear, @ToYear;
```